# What is Ruby Hpricot in Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, hpricot

I am trying to change a ruby script to make it more easily portable. Unfortunately hpricot seems a bit complicated to install on MS Windows and I want to avoid it. My ruby skills are however minimal (or less). How do I replace this with Nokogiri?

```
htmlText = Net::HTTP.get URI.parse("#{ARGV.shift}?type=embed")
html = Hpricot( htmlText )
```

Comment: PS: hpricot is also considered obsolete, nokogiri is way better option

Answer (score 1):

With this

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("#{ARGV.shift}?type=embed"))
```

gotten from http://nokogiri.org/

Comment: Thanks Hauleth, but something is missing there. I get "Invalid argument" (Errno: EINVAL) in "open".

However replacing the last line in my question with just this works:


  html = Nokogiri::HTML( htmlText )

Comment: The `open(...)` call only works if you have open-uri loaded. So you have to `require 'open-uri'` first...